# How do I connect to local MySQL on my Amazon Lightsail instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, prestashop, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I've created new user and database via SSH, so local MySQL works.

I'm trying installation of Prestashop (PHP/MySQL running on my Bitnami LAMP instance) and it says

> Database Server is not found. Please verify the login, password and
>   server fields (DbPDO)

localhost doesn't work, 127.0.0.1 doesn't work either. What should I enter in the field? Should I bind MySQL to 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Using correct username fixed it.